# Magento add FROM-TO filter in column sales grid

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, order-grid

we added a custom column that has integer value. How can we now add a FROM-tO filter like below?

Is there a special command for this?

[image]

```
$this->addColumn('created_at', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
    'index' => 'created_at',
    'type' => 'datetime',
    'width' => '100px',
    'filter_index' => 'main_table.created_at'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

This extension might be helpful, I thinks it is not compatible with the security patch that reworks the way that admin paths work.

https://github.com/ho-nl-fork/magento1-BL_CustomGrid

I'm not the creator of this extension.

Comment: Using it!! Is it under config of the field?

Comment: You should be able to choose what attribute columns you what to see on any Backend groß (products, orders, etc.). Just use the new button above the columns "edit grid" on the right hand side.

Comment: Yes that has been done. But no from to filter.